# Error embedding Metabase dashboard with locked parameters

Tags: metabase

I am creating a dashboard on Metabase to embed it into an application. This dashboard has two questions, one of which was created using the Metabase query builder (AOV) and the other was created using SQL (GMV). When I set the brand_id parameter on the question, I get an error saying that an error ocurred while running the query, but everything works fine for the AOV question. Can you help me?

[image: My dashboard config]

The error that I get is:

Missing id: 
{…}
​
values: Object { values: (60) […], human_readable_values: {}, field_id: 1241 }
​
: Object { … }

And the GMV query is below:

SELECT sum("public"."crm_store_sales"."total") AS "sum"
FROM "public"."crm_store_sales"

WHERE TRUE
[[AND {{ brand_id }}]]
[[AND {{ data }}]]

I am using Metabase 0.31.2 on AWS EKS, using an internal Postgres database and querying another Postgres database.

I am accessing Metabase through Firefox 64 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found an answer: what we did was create a query using native SQL and add a variable to a SQL list. This way it is possible to pass multiple values to it when the question is embedded with a locked variable.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT sum("public"."my_column"."total") AS "sum"
FROM "public"."my_table"

WHERE TRUE
[[AND field1_id in ({{ field1_id }})]]
[[AND {{date}}]]
```

In this example, we created two variables: `field1_id` and `date`. If we embed this question and lock the `field1_id` parameter, we will still be able to pass several values to it, because it is inside a list. For example, you could pass: `1,2,3,4` to this field like this:

```
"params": {
   "field1_id": "1,2,3,4" 
}
```

Please note that there can be no spacing between the elements.

I believe that under the hood Metabase does something like this: `WHERE TRUE AND field1_id IN (1,2,3,4)`.